# Is it possible to get Enum name without creating String() in Golang

Tags: enums, go

Is it possible to get Enum name without creating `func (TheEnum) String() string` in Golang?

```
const (
 MERCURY = 1
 VENUS = iota
 EARTH
 MARS
 JUPITER
 SATURN
 URANUS
 NEPTUNE
 PLUTO
)
```

or is there a way to define constants on the fly? 
I found two ways [struct](http://golang-basic.blogspot.com/2014/07/enumeration-example-golang.html)-based and [string](http://play.golang.org/p/ewMKl6K302)-based, but both way make us retype each  labels 1 more time (or copy-paste and quoting or using editor's macro)

Comment: Also note that [all capital identifiers is not idiomatic Go](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#mixed-caps).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

AFAIK, no you can't do that without explicitly typing the name as a string. But you can use the [`stringer` tool](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer) from the standard tools package to do it for you:

> For example, given this snippet,
>
> ```
> package painkiller
>
> type Pill int
>
> const (
>     Placebo Pill = iota
>     Aspirin
>     Ibuprofen
>     Paracetamol
>     Acetaminophen = Paracetamol
> )
> ```
>
> running this command
>
> ```
> stringer -type=Pill
> ```
>
> in the same directory will create the file pill_string.go, in package painkiller, containing a definition of
>
> ```
> func (Pill) String() string
> ```

This is recommended to use with the `go generate` command of Go 1.4+.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement:
Use the following comment in the code can help `go generate` know what to generate.
Be careful, there is no space between `//` and `go:generate`

```
//go:generate stringer -type=Pill
type Pill int

const (
    Placebo Pill = iota
    Aspirin
    Ibuprofen
    Paracetamol
    Acetaminophen = Paracetamol
)
```