# How to print the string representation of an "enum" in Go?

Tags: go, enums, printf

I've looked at the various official sources for how to do this but I can't find it. Imagine you have the following enum (I know golang doesn't have enums in the classic sense):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type LogLevel int

const (
    Off LogLevel = iota
    Debug
)

var level LogLevel = Debug

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Log Level: %s", level)
}
```

The closest I can get with the above `%s`, which gives me:

```
Log Level: %!s(main.LogLevel=1)
```

I would like to have:

```
Log Level: Debug
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get Enum name without creating String() in Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187132/is-it-possible-to-get-enum-name-without-creating-string-in-golang)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't directly within the language, but there's a tool for generating the supporting code: [golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer)

From the example in the `stringer` docs

```
type Pill int

const (
    Placebo Pill = iota
    Aspirin
    Ibuprofen
    Paracetamol
    Acetaminophen = Paracetamol
)
```

Would produce code like

```
const _Pill_name = "PlaceboAspirinIbuprofenParacetamol"

var _Pill_index = [...]uint8{0, 7, 14, 23, 34}

func (i Pill) String() string {
    if i < 0 || i+1 >= Pill(len(_Pill_index)) {
        return fmt.Sprintf("Pill(%d)", i)
    }
    return _Pill_name[_Pill_index[i]:_Pill_index[i+1]]
}
```

Comment: This is very brittle code and doesn't solve the DRY problem. If you're going to go in that direction, might as well just have an explicit and simple `String()` method with a switch for each const.

Comment: @ZephaniahGrunschlag: that's what this example does; it generates a simple String method, except you don't have to maintain it yourself, or even look at the generated code. Using the `stringer` package is fairly common in go projects. It's not intended to create a true enum, the String() output isn't meant for any comparison or verification, it's just a convenient method of creating human readable output. You don't need to downvote an answer because you don't like the Go community's choice of solution.

Answer (score -3):

This works for me:

`level_str = fmt.SPrintf("%s", level)`